# Tensorflow Lite: ImportError: libusb-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, raspberry-pi, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I'm new to using Tensorflow and need to for a project of mine. The goal is to create a live object recognition system on a RPi4 and I've been stuck in dependency hell. I'm running this on a clean Oraclebox VM that has the RPi4 OS, VSCode and Conda. Tensorflow provides a basic example of this system which I was going to adapt for my project: [github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/raspberry_pi](https://stackoverflow.com)

I tried running the example code after following installation instructions and received this:

```
(tflite_env) kerdis01@raspberry:~/examples/lite/examples/image_classification/raspberry_pi $ python classify.py  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "classify.py", line 21, in <module>     from tflite_support.task import core   File "/home/kerdis01/miniconda3/envs/tflite_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tflite_support/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>     from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.python import metadata   File "/home/kerdis01/miniconda3/envs/tflite_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/python/metadata.py", line 30, in <module>     from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.cc.python import _pywrap_metadata_version ImportError: libusb-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is my current package list in my env:

```
# packages in environment at /home/kerdis01/miniconda3/envs/tflite_env:

# 

# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
absl-py                   2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
argparse                  1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.3.11            h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
comm                      0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.7            py38h6a678d5_0  
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
flatbuffers               20181003210633           pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        7.1.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        7.1.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.29.3             pyhd33586a_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.12.2             pyh41d4057_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.2            py38h578d9bd_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_0  
libgcc-ng                 13.2.0               h807b86a_5    conda-forge
libgomp                   13.2.0               h807b86a_5    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.24.4                   pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python-headless    4.9.0.80                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.2.1                hd590300_1    conda-forge
packaging                 24.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       24.0                     pypi_0    pypi
platformdirs              4.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.42             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.42               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.20.3                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.8            py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pybind11                  2.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21                     pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.17.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.8.19               h955ad1f_0  
python-dateutil           2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      2_cp38    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.2           py38h6a678d5_0  
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
setuptools                68.2.2           py38h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sounddevice               0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0  
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tflite-support            0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
tornado                   6.4              py38h01eb140_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.14.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.10.0             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.41.2           py38h06a4308_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h5eee18b_0  
zeromq                    4.3.5                h6a678d5_0  
zipp                      3.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0
```

I had to change the install script so that opencv-python-headless was installed as that got rid of another error to do with libgl not existing.

Upon googling the issue I found a few potential fixes that I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0 
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

But no luck.

I'm trying to keep this build as light as possible but any suggestions would be a great help.